# Why does Django give errors with settings when started from script but not interactively?

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I'm trying to start a mini-Django test server using some fixed data, for testing.

When run interactively (from the REPL) loop, it runs correctly, when executed as part of a script by `python myscript.py`, it fails.  I'm guessing there's something different in the environment, but what?

**Code:**

```
import os
import sys
import json
import resttest
import unittest
from multiprocessing import Process
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

server_process = None
prefix = 'http://localhost:8000'

path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('testapp') # Django project is separate and in subfolder 'testapp'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testapp.settings")
config_args = list()
config_args.append('')
config_args.append('testserver')
config_args.append('test_data.json')
proc = Process(target=execute_from_command_line, args=[config_args])
proc.start()
os.chdir(path)
```

**Error:**

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'testapp.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named testapp.settings
```

**Context:**

I'm working on a small Python project for testing & benchmarking REST services. It makes use of pycurl bindings to provide low-level control of the HTTP requests issued, to facilitate testing. To ensure that it is correctly using pycurl, I have created a basic Django REST API to use in functional testing.

Comment: Which django version do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the parent directory of `testapp/` to the Python path.

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/directory/")
```

You can determine this location programmatically of course; the commands used to do so depend on where your script is in comparison to the testapp location. You can drop the `os.getcwd()` and `os.chdir()`. It's the PYTHONPATH that matters, not the working directory. You are specifying the settings module environment variable correctly, but [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) make note of properly setting the Python import search path.

*Aside 1:* take a look at `django.core.management.call_command`. It's a shortcut, though you still need to setup the settings module. `call_command('testserver', 'test_data.json')`

*Aside 2:* You can skip setting an environment variable as mentioned in the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings). In your case:

```
from django.conf import settings
from testapp import settings as my_settings

settings.configure(my_settings)
```

Comment: This did, indeed fix it.  To you go the thanks and the bounty (it's always environment settings that cause the grief).

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD` to your `.env`?

Comment: While this may work, it is not optimal because I do not want to tie my project to my local install (this is a GitHub published project).